# GDAL FileGDB Driver with Anaconda / ArcGIS Pro

Tags: gdal, arcgis-pro, anaconda

I have installed GDAL using the ArcGIS Pro (2.1.2) Package Manager. This has installed GDAL 2.2.2, which runs fine, except that it didn't install the FileGDB driver which is what I need it for. It is not in the ogr driver list, there is no `gdal-plugins` folder on my computer and no `FileGDB.dll` as well. Whenever I open the Python command prompt I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the specified path.

(arcgispro-py3) C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\etc\conda\activate.d>set "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH="

(arcgispro-py3) C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3>
```

Whatever path I specify in the `gdal-activate.bat` file, it keeps throwing that same error. I have also tried adding GDAL_DRIVER_PATH manually to my environment variables, but keep getting the same error. I have tried this with a clean install of ArcGIS Pro, installing only gdal, and it throws the same error.

How do I get GDAL to find my FileGDB.dll file?

Comment: ArcPy has a more complete version of file geodatabase support than is available in FileGDB API.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a PostGIS database into a filegeodatabase with Arcpy? Because that is what I want to use the driver for, since writing into a fgdb is not possible with the default gdb driver.

Comment: There are only five or six ways to do that with ArcPy.

Comment: Having same issue