# Adding support to Esri's FileGDB driver when fiona/gdal/osgeo were installed through Anaconda

Tags: python, gdal, file-geodatabase, windows, osgeo

Is there a way to tweak the fiona/gdal/osgeo packages installed through Anaconda so that they can be used to read/write GDB files using the [ESRI FileGDB driver](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm)? The main thing I'm actually trying to achieve is **writing** to GDB a file.

I have found multiple answers online, but all of them involve re-installing OSGeo or GDAL from the python wheel files. **These methods do not work for me because I installed fiona, OSGeo and GDAL using Anaconda**. So none of the solutions I found online (listed below) seem to work. Furthermore, the approach of overwriting conda's whole installation of GDAL using `pip install` also does not work.

I have already downloaded the DLL file from ESRI, placed it in my `C:\...\Lib\site-packages\osgeo` folder and added a new environment variable called `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` indicating the appropriate path. However, contrary to the suggestions in the posts listed below, the `__init__.py` inside the `osgeo` folder does not have a commented line that reads `os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'gdalplugins')`. Therefore, I am not sure where to include this line in my own file system.

Similar (unresolved) discussions can be found on the [GeoPandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/868) and on the [Fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/565) Github pages.

Also, here is a list of related posts/questions/sites with relevant info but which ultimately did not solve my problem.

- [How to add support for FileGDB (Esri file gdb API) driver in
  fiona?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona)
- [How to edit file geodatabase in Python using FileGDB Driver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279612/how-to-edit-file-geodatabase-in-python-using-filegdb-driver)
- [Geopandas: Write layer back into GeoDataBase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231265/geopandas-write-layer-back-into-geodatabase)
- [Exporting PostGIS Data](https://black-tea.github.io/setup-notes/2017/06/16/Exporting-PostGIS-Data.html)
- [Setting up GDAL/OGR with FileGDB Driver for Python on Windows](https://glenbambrick.com/2017/03/10/setting-up-gdal-with-filegdb/)
- [GDAL FileGDB Driver with Anaconda / ArcGIS Pro (Unanswered)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279756/gdal-filegdb-driver-with-anaconda-arcgis-pro)
- [GDAL Documentation on using ESRI File Geodatabase (FileGDB)](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html)
- [How to access feature classes in file geodatabases with Python and GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32762/how-to-access-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabases-with-python-and-gdal)
- [ESRI FileGDB API on GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/)

### How I installed Fiona and other packages:

I'm currently using Windows 10. After installing Anaconda, I created a new environment called `myenv` and installed the main libraries I was going to use:

```
conda create -n myenv pandas geopandas fiona spyder numpy scipy
```

GDAL was automatically installed as one of the associated/required packages for fiona and geopandas.

In my command prompt, when I activate `myenv` and type `gdalinfo --version`, I get the following response:

```
GDAL 3.0.2, released 2019/10/28
```

When I use the python-based route, I get the same answer.

```
import osgeo.gdal
print(osgeo.gdal.__version__)
>3.0.2
```

### Overwriting conda's installation of GDAL using `pip install GDALxyz.whl`

I downloaded the GDAL wheels from the [`gohlke` repository](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and ran `pip install "GDAL-3.3.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"`, added Estri's FileGDB driver DLLs into the appropriate folders, added the appropriate environment variables and it still didn't work.

### Additional Notes:

If the answer involves something like "you need to compile/build GDAL from source files", please include a step-by-step on how to do so, including what to do after "building" (for example, where to put the files and how to get Python to use the newly-built version of GDAL within a specific conda environment). I know this is a lot to ask, and I apologize for doing so. It's just that I have tried looking into this process and it is not very newbie-friendly.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include how you installed gdal using conda and also which version of gdal you have installed on your conda environment?

Comment: There! added both pieces of information. I hope it helps! =)

Comment: FileGDB support requires two things, 1. the **Esri** FileGDB API library (stored in a directory in your `PATH`) *and* 2. the **GDAL** FileGDB driver (either compiled into the GDAL library itself or compiled separately as a driver plugin and stored in the `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH`). You only have 1. (the API library) and I don't think Anaconda or conda-forge provide a filegdb enabled GDAL or a driver plugin so you're out of luck there.  You *may* be able to get it to work if you can find and download a version of the driver as a plugin compiled for the same version of gdal that your conda env provides

Comment: Are you sure that you cant do it? I think if you go through our discussion there Brendan confirmed that this driver list where you find FileGDB with only r option is not really in use. Or did you try and it didn't work/ and I understood something wrong or missread the code in pyogrio. Anyway if you managed to find gdal drivers with FileGDB support you should be definitely able to use GDAL. Or did you use the OpenFileGDB driver with only read support?
If you have the FileGDB somehow compiled into GDAL (or is it just an extension, I don't know?) then I would try this here (adapted from read to m

Comment: You should probably add windows as a tag, it actually makes your problem harder than usual. Also, you can always install pip packages over the ones in the Anaconda environment. This is the go-to source for people who know what packages they need but can't or don't want to bother with the hassle of building them on Windows: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: This is still your best bet probably: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona. Then again, writing to FileGDB may not be necessary, GeoPackage works just as well (and far easier to work with)

Comment: Yep, looked into that already and it was a no go, sadly. I've been working with GeoPackages, but I still would like to figure out how to actually write GDB files.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the dirty little trick to do pip install although conda is used in principle. That usually works.
With that it could be easier to get fiona compiled.
I tested the build instructions for windows from the fiona help page and they actually worked where I used OSGeo4W as the precompiled gdal source .
I guess you have to fork fiona, clone it to local with git or download it and within the source you might want search for allowed drivers and at least add FileGDB there if it isnt allowed yet.
Otherwise in the gitter channel of geopandas there was some hints about how to compile pyogrio in the right way. But actually in pyogrio code you really have to extend that allowed driver list. Because it actually also prevented me to use openapi, although it worked fine on gdal to open an url in a dataset.
Nope isnt there for my gdal install
https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-list-of-ogr-drivers-alphabetically-a-z
And I cannot make sense of this here either:
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4420
from https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html#vector-filegdb
tricky stuff

Comment: In your answer, you say "add FileGDB there." Can you be a bit more specific about how someone would do that? That's the heart of my question and I can't find a good answer for it.

Comment: I also forgot to mention: your answer contains instructions about how to install Fiona on a fresh new Python environment (i.e., an environment in which Fiona & GDAL haven't yet been installed). But my original question is: consider that Fiona and GDAL have **already** been installed using Anaconda. In that case, is it possible to tweak the libraries in Python to get the `FileGDB` driver to work? Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: I just updated the body of my main question, but I just wanted to respond here: using `pip install` to overwrite the GDAL installation using the `whl` file from the gohlke repository didn't work, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

You could actually also use gdal to open the dataset and iterate through its features, which is slow but should work. OGR/GDAL cookbook
https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#load-data-to-memory <-Does that help you to get started with gdal for example?
That is where I started to work with gdal and where I come back to when analysing the sources of fiona and pyogrio. GDAL is slow but should be working, if you know how to get FileGDB working within gdal that is. Much easier though than to build the python libraries from skratch.
Chance that you find a non conda repo with built in FileGDB is bigger. Than you can pip install that one into your conda environment? I would start with that and with GDAL.
I will crosscheck if FileGDB works with my installed GDAL which is somehow supplied by osgeo

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the extra info! The problem I'm trying to solve isn't reading data using the FileGDB driver. To **read** GDB files, I can use the OpenFileGDB driver that already comes pre-packaged with OSGEO/GDAL. The problem I'm really trying to solve is **writing** to a GDB file. Sadly, that's something that I can't do using pyogrio or the OpenFileGDB driver.

Comment: Ah ok yeah so then you cant really use that above stuff.
I guess without that FileGDB you will be more or less stuck
Obivously because it's propriatery stuff
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB

Comment: But yeah I havent build yet succesfully GDAL on windows. You can use the instructions but then I got stuck with proj.
Anyway one thing to peak into could be this script here:
https://github.com/srenoes/Fiona/blob/master/scripts/travis_gdal_install.sh
 Make and make install is typically for unix though, but who knows if this isnt also  usable in windows.
Otherwise I scan repos I know using the libraries of interest to find building scripts and usually there is some for the platforms Appveyor and/or Travis

Comment: Thanks for the info! But like I said in my request for the bounty, if adding support to the `FileGDB` driver requires building GDAL from scratch, I'm going to need a bit more detail on how to do so because, like you, I also got lost trying to understand what needs to be done. Also, consider that I'm someone who isn't super familiar with compiling C codes from sourcefiles either. I understand the concept and have even done so myself for veeeeeery simple programs many years ago. But for something like this, I'm going to need a bit more clarity. Thanks again, btw!!!